# How to ignore NA in ifelse statement

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I came to R from SAS, where numeric missing is set to infinity. So we can just say:

```
positiveA = A > 0;
```

In R, I have to be verbose like:

```
positiveA <- ifelse(is.na(A),0, ifelse(A > 0, 1, 0))
```

I find this syntax is hard to read. Is there anyway I can modify ifelse function to consider NA a special value that is always false for all comparison conditions? If not, considering NA as -Inf will work too.

Similarly, setting NA to '' (blank) in ifelse statement for character variables.

Thanks.

Comment: As everyone has already said: do NOT replace NA with logical or numeric values.  Many R functions have a "na.rm=TRUE/FALSE" or similar argument to allow you to process your data appropriately. If SAS really sets things to Inf, they are violating fundamental computer math rules (not to mention that Inf is an allowable result of a math expression, as is NaN (= 0/0 , e.g.)) ; whereas NA means something completely different.   Once you get used to the philosophy of R, you'll be more comfortable allowing NA to remain NA.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This syntax is easier to read:

```
x <- c(NA, 1, 0, -1)

(x > 0) & (!is.na(x)) 
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

(The outer parentheses aren't necessary, but will make the statement easier to read for almost anyone other than the machine.)

---

**Edit**:

```
## If you want 0s and 1s
((x > 0) & (!is.na(x))) * 1
# [1] 0 1 0 0
```

Finally, you can make the whole thing into a function:

```
isPos <- function(x) {
    (x > 0) & (!is.na(x)) * 1
}

isPos(x)
# [1] 0 1 0 0
```

Comment: This is very cool, Josh. Is `positiveA <- ifelse(x > 0 & !is.na(x), 1, 0)` the best I can get?

Comment: @AdamNYC -- Thanks. There's really no need here for any `ifelse()` call. (See my edit.)

Comment: I actually need to convert T/F to 1/0 to aggregate it. (The statement in SAS gives me 1/0). Is there a better way to do this in R (i.e., avoiding ifelse).

Comment: Just for your reference, it's based on the fact that the basic arithmetic operators "[coerce logical vectors] to integer or numeric vectors, ‘FALSE’ having value zero and ‘TRUE’ having value one." (Quoted text from `?Arithmetic`, also reached by `?*`.) Try also `sum(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)); TRUE + c(TRUE, FALSE)`, etc.

Answer (score 10):

Replacing a `NA` value with zero seems rather strange behaviour to expect. `R` considers `NA` values missing (although hidden far behind scenes where you (never) need to go they are negative very large numbers when numeric ))

All you need to do is `A>0` or `as.numeric(A>0)` if you want 0,1 not TRUE , FALSE

```
# some dummy data
A <- seq(-1,1,l=11)
# add NA value as second value
A[2] <- NA
positiveA <- A>0
positiveA
 [1] FALSE    NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

 as.numeric(positiveA) # 
 [1]  0 NA  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1
```

note that 
`ifelse(A>0, 1,0)` would also work.

The `NA` values are "retained", or dealt with appropriately. `R` is sensible here.

Comment: I think NA is not really a negative number in R: NA < 0 yields NA. What I would like is not to have to specify a special case for NA in my statement, b/c most of the times, NA won't meet my condition

Comment: Yes, R is sensible. If something is `NA`, then `R` will consider it `NA`, however, deep within the source code (C or FORTRAN, these NA values will be very large negative values, but it will rarely be of any concern unless you are poking around there.

Comment: In this case, the `NA` is ignored by the condition, which is what you want, you don't want it to replace `NA` with `0`, because `NA` implies missing values.

Comment: What do you mean "although hidden far behind scenes they are negative very large numbers when numeric"? I'm intrigued.

Comment: From  [data.table](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1043&group_id=240&atid=978) -- I'm believing Matthew Dowle here, but I assume he has done the required looking.

Comment: Hi mnel, I don't want to replace NA with zero (as mentioned in the question). -Inf will probably work for most of the cases (as it works in SAS)

Comment: I have a couple hundred variable transformations, and retyping (ifelse(is.na(x1)), 0 for all of statements is time consuming :)

Comment: Thanks mnel for your patience. A > 0 will give me NA if A is NA, which is not I want. Practically, my statements are actually more complicated than that (multiple nested ifelse). For example, I need to create a new variable conditional on 4 other variables. Adding is.na for each of these variables will add another 4 layers of nested ifelse to my statement.

Comment: There will be better ways than nested ifelse statements.

Comment: Thanks @mnel. That makes sense, I guess. Interesting to learn that that internal detail could possibly impact the sort algorithm that gets dispatched on a numeric vector!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
positiveA <- ifelse(!is.na(A) & A > 0, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with integers you can use %in%

For example, if your numbers can go up to 2

```
test <- c(NA, 2, 1, 0, -1)
```

other people has suggested to use

```
(test > 0) & (!is.na(test))
or
ifelse(!is.na(test) & test > 0, 1, 0)
```

my solution is simpler and gives you the same result.

```
test %in% 1:2
```

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use the missing argument i `if_else_` from `hablar`:

```
library(hablar) 

x <- c(NA, 1, 0, -1)

if_else_(x > 0, T, F, missing = F)
```

which gives you

```
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```