# R handling NA values while doing a comparison ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement, na

how can i tell > and < operators to ignore NA values? Below code return NA on 1st row. I want it to return 0 as both conditions fail on that row

```
##sum by values
df <- data.frame(sex=c('M','F','M'),occupation=c('Student','Analyst','Analyst'),age=c(NA,6,9), marks=c(34,65,21))
df
#df$counting <- ifelse(df$age > 5 & df$age < 8, 1, 0)
df$counting <- ifelse(df$age > 5 & df$age < 8, 1, 0)+ifelse(df$marks > 60 & df$marks < 70, 1, 0)
df
```

Comment: Good practice is to clean the dataset before any analysis. So try to remove all NAs by imputing with some other values or smiply with `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the following SO post: [How to ignore NA in ifelse statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598511/how-to-ignore-na-in-ifelse-statement)

With respect to your question:

```
df$counting <- ifelse(df$age > 5 & df$age < 8 & !is.na(df$age), 1, 0) + ifelse(df$marks > 60 & df$marks < 70, 1, 0)
> df
  sex occupation age marks counting
1   M    Student  NA    34        0
2   F    Analyst   6    65        2
3   M    Analyst   9    21        0
```

Comment: here's a dplyr solution

df = df %>% group_by_all() %>% mutate(counting = sum(c(age > 5 & age < 8, marks > 60 & marks < 70), na.rm=T)) %>% ungroup()

Answer (score 0):

you could also use `cut` or `findInterval`.

```
 df$counting <- colSums(rbind(cut(df$age, c(5,8), labels=F),cut(df$marks, c(60,70),    labels=F)), na.rm=T)
 df
 #  sex occupation age marks counting
 #1   M    Student  NA    34        0
 #2   F    Analyst   6    65        2
 #3   M    Analyst   9    21        0
```