# R - handling NA in ifelse statements

Tags: r, if-statement, replace, na

This question is slightly similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598511/how-to-ignore-na-in-ifelse-statement) with a more theoretical component.

Given df below:

```
varA <- c(1,0,0,NA,NA)
varB <- c(NA,NA,NA,1,0)
df <- data.frame(varA, varB)

varA varB
1    NA
0    NA
0    NA
NA    1
NA    0
```

**What's the most elegant method to generate `var` (with consideration given to NA) which combines the information from `varA` and `varB`?**

```
varA varB var
1    NA   1
0    NA   0
0    NA   0
NA    1   1
NA    0   0
```

My approach, right now, is as follows:

```
df$var[df$varA == 1 | df$varB == 1] <- 1
df$var[df$varA == 0 | df$varB == 0] <- 0
```

As a side question, how does R handle NA in `ifelse` statements? For example, if I write the following code, it does not produce the output I intended.

```
df$var <- ifelse(df$varA == 1 | df$varB == 1, 1, 
            ifelse(df$varA == 0 | df$varB == 0, 0, NA)
```

Comment: Try `rowSums`..

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"?  sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> combines the information from varA and varB

Seems like you are looking for `coalesce`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(var = coalesce(varA, varB))

#  varA varB var
#1    1   NA   1
#2    0   NA   0
#3    0   NA   0
#4   NA    1   1
#5   NA    0   0
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For your purposes, NA is equivalent to 0, so why not convert them to 0?

```
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
df$var <- with(df, as.integer(varA | varB))

> df
  varA varB var
1    1    0   1
2    0    0   0
3    0    0   0
4    0    1   1
5    0    0   0
```

Comment: Missing could be an important source of information. Thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `pmax`

```
df$var <- do.call(pmax, c(df, na.rm = TRUE))
df$var
#[1] 1 0 0 1 0
```